# insert multi line text into list using spservices

Tags: list, spservices, html

How to insert multi line text data into share point list using spservices.
I have tried beloow code but its not working

```
 $().SPServices({
        operation: "UpdateListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "List",
        ID: ticketid,
        valuepairs: [["Feedback", multifeedback]],
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {

        }
    });
```

Design:

```
<textarea class="multiline" id="multifeedback" ></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just say multifeedback in your value pair. You'd have to do:

```
$().SPServices({
        operation: "UpdateListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "List",
        ID: ticketid,
        valuepairs: [["Feedback", $("#multifeedback").val()]],
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {

        }
    });
```